Multiple Choice Not Display in Latest PowerApps Table
Currently, I'm integrating my SharePoint list data into PowerApps to display all columns. However, I discovered that the latest version of the table can't display any multiple-choice data. I'm trying to figure out how to concatenate it, but I still haven't found a way to configure the column properly.
This is the new Table inside the PowerApps Studio
This is the data inside the SharePoint list which couldn't display into PowerApps
